# (C++) How to make a for loop that creates certain number of class's object

Tags: c++

How does one make a for loop that creates a certain number of class objects with names that add in numerical order.

example struct:

```
struct Point{
    int x, y;

    Point(int inputx, int inputy){
        x = inputx;
        y = inputy;
        }

    };
```

How would I implement a for loop to create  Point Point1(x,y), Point Point2(x,y), Point Point3(x,y), etc.

Comment: Why don't you use array of objects instead?

Comment: Use macros? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't create variables names like that using a loop.

Perhaps a `std::map<int, Point>` will work for your needs.

```
std::map<int, Point> pointsMap;
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i )
{
   pointsMap[i+1] = Point{...}:
}
```

Then, can use `pointMap[n]` to access the items from the map.

If you want to use a string as the key of the map, you can construct the keys in the loop using `i`.

```
std::map<std::string, Point> pointsMap;
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i )
{
   std::string key = "Point" + std::to_string(i+1);
   pointsMap[key] = Point{...}:
}
```

Then, can use `pointMap[key]` to access the items from the map.

Comment: Map is overkill. Array is enough.

Comment: @Igor, I thought of it but relented in favor of a `map` since it lead nicely into being able use a `string` as the key.

Answer (score 0):

Symbol names are compile-time entities not present in the compiled run-time code, so generating a symbol name at run-time makes no sense. Instead you would use an array or container class.